# python tox - No such file or directory error

Tags: python, packaging

I have a project, let's say called `'my_project'` with the following structure:

```
my_project
|
 tox.ini
 setup.py
 src
 |
  client.py
  server.py
  config.json
  # other files
  tests.py
```

The classes defined in files `client.py` and `server.py` use information contained in `config.json` and `tests.py` implements the `py.test` tests for each file in folder src. Inside the client/server files I read the config file as follows:

```
with open('./config.json') as infile:
     self.parameters = json.load(infile)
```

Next, I created a tox.ini file as follows:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,cov

[testenv]
#commands = py.test --cov=src/client.py src/tests.py -v
commands = py.test -sv --doctest-modules src/__init__.py src/tests.py


[testenv:py27]
commands = coverage erase
           coverage run --source=src -m pytest
           coverage report -m
deps = pytest
```

But when I run the `tox` command I get an error: `"No such file or directory: 'config.json'"`. How can I setup up the correct path to make sure that `tox` can find all necessary files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to open `'./config.json'` will always make Python look in the process's current directory; that's just how filepaths work.  If you want to open the `config.json` file in the same directory as the `.py` file that's doing the opening, you need to include the path of the directory containing the `.py` file:

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.json')) as infile:
```